# How do i add gaps between drawn lines with linerenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DrawHorizontalLines : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject objectToDrawLines;
    public int linesCount;
    public int linesLength;
    public int linesGap;

    void Start()
    {
        LineRenderer l = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

        List<Vector3> pos = new List<Vector3>();
        pos.Add(objectToDrawLines.transform.position);

        for (int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject line = new GameObject();
            line.transform.position = new Vector3(objectToDrawLines.transform.position.x + linesLength, objectToDrawLines.transform.position.y, objectToDrawLines.transform.position.z);
            pos.Add(line.transform.position);
            l.startWidth = 0.1f;
            l.endWidth = 0.1f;
            l.SetPositions(pos.ToArray());
            l.useWorldSpace = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and i also want to make sure that always the first line will start from the objectToDrawLines bottom(one side edge) and will end the upper(other side edge)

so the first line position and the last line position will be on both edges positions of the objectToDRawLines.

so if for example i have a cube scale on the x to 56 so the first drawn line will be on the left side of the cube position and the last line on the right end side of the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your current code there is exactly **once single line**.

The additional `GameObject line` you create has nothing on it - those are just invisible empty objects.

> and I also want to make sure that always the first line will start from the objectToDrawLines bottom(one side edge) and will end the upper(other side edge)

assuming this is achieved via purely the **scale** it would be easier to use a local position and convert it to global space. Also assuming here this component is attached to the accordingly scaled cube you mentioned

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesCount; i++)
{ 
    // y will be linear interpolated and go from 0 to 1
    var y = Mathf.Lerp(-0.5f, 0.5f, i / (linesCount - 1));
    // the left edge of the object in local space
    var startLocal = new Vector3(-0.5f, y, 0);
    // the right edge of the object in local space
    var endLocal = new Vector3(0.5f, y, 0);

    // actually add the lineRenderer to your new objects -> multiple lines
    // this would be even easier using a pre-configured prefab!
    var line = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    // use local space
    line.useWorldSpace = false;
    // make the line a child of this object
    line.transform.SetParet(transform, false);
    line.startWidth = 0.1f;
    line.endWidth = 0.1f;
    // you will need to get a material from somewhere otherwise your new lines will be pink
    //TODO line.material = lineMaterial;
    line.positionCount = 2;
    line.SetPosition(0, startLocal);
    line.SetPosition(1, endLocal);
}
```

or if you need the line positions to stay in global space - for instance if you explicitly do **not** want to move them if the cube is moved - you can simply convert them

```
var startWorld = transform.TransformPoint(startLocal);
var endWorld = transform.TransformPoint(endLocal);
```

and then stick to

```
line.useWorldSpace = true;
line.SetPosition(0, startWorld);
line.SetPosition(1, endWorld);
```

[image]

As mentioned the advantage of the local space is that you can move/rotate/scale your cube afterwards and the lines will follow it.

[image]

Comment: isn't creating multiple linerenderer components will affect the performance?

Comment: @SharonHemed .. well to some extend sure, just like creating multiple GameObjects or meshes

Comment: The reason i want to do it is that I have a slider in unity3d and i want to add to the slider ticks(lines) with values near each tick like in a trackbar.  https://imgur.com/a/57Xggbr for example on the slider on the left the scale one I want that to have ticks coming out from the black line and then value near each one 1,2,3,4,5 so when i move the slider i will know on what value it is.

Comment: sounds a bit like this would better be solved using a texture/shader as it is rather more a tiny display detail .. but you *can* go with the LineRenderer until you note that it indeed is a huge performance issue